# Qt Creator closeEvent issue

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

Im having a weird problem with Qt creator, Im new to Qt and C++ so I dont know why this is happening:

This is from mainwindow.cpp:

```
void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    Funct();
    event->ignore();
}

void Funct(void)
{
    return;
}
```

And this is from mainwindow.h:

```
#include </*Stuff*/>
#include <QCloseEvent>

class NotepadWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT 

    public:
        NotepadWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~NotepadWindow();

    protected:
        void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);

    private:
        void Funct();
    /*More stuff*/
};
```

And the error:

```
D:\Users\...\notepadwindow.cpp:480: error: C3861: 'Funct': cannot find identifier
```

Im really lost with this :/
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace 
`void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)`

with `void NotepadWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)`

Without the `NotepadWindow::` that function is not part of the class, and the compiler doesn't know what `Funct` you're talking about.

Then do the same with Funct, replace `void Funct(void)` with `void NotepadWindow::Funct(void)` so the compiler knows you're implementing the class's function, and not a separate unrelated function.

Comment: Oh, Thanks!!, really, that was a really stupid error

Comment: @user291252 feel free to accept the answer if that's all you need.